# Regarding magento extension Unirgy_StoreLocator

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I am using magento 1.5 version for my project. I had 1.4 version installed in my localhost. i tried this extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Unirgy/extension/956/google-maps-store-locator
and i installed in 1.4 its working fine . 
i cant install in 1.5 ( live server) bcoz the extension will not support 1.5
so i copied files from 1.4 to 1.5 live server.
it was not displaying map. but the outer structure and fields are coming
Please help us to resolve this issue

Comment: i had given api key also.but not working. can u please resolve this at the earliest

Answer (score 0):

Contact Unirgy (the maker of the extension) and ask if they are going to update it to work with recent versions. Perhaps you can persuade them to.